# Replicate columns using a dynamic name series based on the current year

Tags: r, function, dplyr, data.table

I am looking to either:

- write a function or
- use a data.table or
- use dplyr mutate_cond or
- use the purr map function

to replicate this functionality:

```
If year = current
    columns(7,8,9) = column(6)
Else
    If year = current + 1
        columns(8,9,10) = column(7)
    Else
        If year = current + 2
            columns(9,10,11) = column(8)
        Else
            If year = current + 3
                columns(10,11,12) = column9)
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If
```

So far I have been able to create a static solution using the following untidy code:

```
tbl.scholar1<-tbl.scholar1%>%mutate_cond(cohort == currentAY, ay_1819=ay_1718, ay_1920=ay_1718, ay_2021=ay_1718)
tbl.scholar1<-tbl.scholar1%>%mutate_cond(cohort == currentAY+1, ay_1920=ay_1819, ay_2021=ay_1819, ay_2122=ay_1819)
tbl.scholar1<-tbl.scholar1%>%mutate_cond(cohort == currentAY+2, ay_2021=ay_1920, ay_2122=ay_1920, ay_2223=ay_1920)
tbl.scholar1<-tbl.scholar1%>%mutate_cond(cohort == currentAY+3, ay_2122=ay_2021, ay_2223=ay_2021, ay_2324=ay_2021)
```

After some hacking around I wrote a function that takes the current year and column names as input:

```
tbl.scholar1<-dup.DF(tbl.scholar1, currentYR, "ay_1718", "ay_2324")
```

The function code looks like this

```
dup.DF <- function(df1, currAY, name1, name2) {

  df1%>%mutate_cond(cohort == currAY, UQ(rlang::sym(name2)) :=  UQ(rlang::sym(name1)))              #This works!!!!

}
```

So somehow I know there is a more elegant solution using a data.table, purrr:map or dplyr to take in a dynamic variable as a vector or list so that I don't have to repeat my function n number of iterations with a for loop.

```
The input looks like this....
    SYSDATE     ID           name           cohort fundCode ay_1718 ay_1819 ay_1920  ay_2021  ay_2122  ay_2223  ay_2324  ay_2425
0005-11-20  000000000   "last0, first"       1718    316001    1         0     0         0        0         0        0       0
0005-11-20  000000000   "last0, first"       1718    316001    0         1     0         0        0         0        0       0
0005-11-20  000000000   "last0, first"       1718    316001    0         0     1         0        0         0        0       0
0005-11-20  000000000   "last0, first"       1718    316001    0         0     0         1        0         0        0       0
```

My expected output is...

```
    SYSDATE     ID           name           cohort fundCode ay_1718 ay_1819 ay_1920  ay_2021  ay_2122  ay_2223  ay_2324  ay_2425
0005-11-20  000000000   "last0, first"       1718    316001    1         1     1         1        0         0        0       0
0005-11-20  000000000   "last0, first"       1718    316001    0         1     1         1        1         0        0       0
0005-11-20  000000000   "last0, first"       1718    316001    0         0     1         1        1         1        0       0
0005-11-20  000000000   "last0, first"       1718    316001    0         0     0         1        1         1        1       0
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: The input looks like this...

Comment: Also I added the expected output. I am currently using the mutate_cond  code four times to generate the output but I think there is a better way to accomplish this.

Comment: your sample data does not seem to contain anything related to your code. did u label the columns wrongly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer -** After getting OP's clarification on the requirement I had to change the approach.

```r
st_pos <- 6                         #concerned column's start position in the given dataframe
df_bkp <- df                        #data backup

#rename concerned columns as "ay_1718", "ay_1819" etc
names(df)[st_pos:ncol(df)] <- paste("ay", paste0(as.numeric(substr(min(df$year), 1, 2)) + 0:(ncol(df) - st_pos),
                                                 as.numeric(substr(min(df$year), 3, 4)) + 0:(ncol(df) - st_pos)), 
                                    sep="_")

#copy "year" column's value to the ensuing three columns
cols <- names(df)[st_pos:ncol(df)]  #renamed columns
mapply(function(x, y) 
  df[df$year == x & df$ID == y, which(grepl(x, cols)) + (st_pos-1):(st_pos+2)] <<- 
    df[df$year == x & df$ID == y, which(grepl(x, cols)) + (st_pos-1)],
  df$year, df$ID)
```

which gives

```
> df
     SYSDATE ID         name year fundCode ay_1718 ay_1819 ay_1920 ay_2021 ay_2122 ay_2223 ay_2324 ay_2425
1 0005-11-20  0 last0, first 1718   316001     700     700     700     700       0       0       0       0
2 0005-11-20  1 last1, first 1819   316002       0      60      60      60      60       0       0       0
3 0005-11-20  2 last2, first 1920   316003       0       0      50      50      50      50       0       0
4 0005-11-20  3 last3, first 2021   316004       0       0       0     400     400     400     400       0
```

**Sample data:** (note: I have slightly modified value of `Y1, Y2 etc` from `1` to some other value for illustration purpose)

```
df <- structure(list(SYSDATE = c("0005-11-20", "0005-11-20", "0005-11-20", 
"0005-11-20"), ID = 0:3, name = c("last0, first", "last1, first", 
"last2, first", "last3, first"), year = c(1718L, 1819L, 1920L, 
2021L), fundCode = 316001:316004, Y1 = c(700L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Y2 = c(0L, 
60L, 0L, 0L), Y3 = c(0L, 0L, 50L, 0L), Y4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 400L
), Y5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Y6 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Y7 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), Y8 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("SYSDATE", "ID", 
"name", "year", "fundCode", "Y1", "Y2", "Y3", "Y4", "Y5", "Y6", 
"Y7", "Y8"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

#     SYSDATE ID         name year fundCode  Y1 Y2 Y3  Y4 Y5 Y6 Y7 Y8
#1 0005-11-20  0 last0, first 1718   316001 700  0  0   0  0  0  0  0
#2 0005-11-20  1 last1, first 1819   316002   0 60  0   0  0  0  0  0
#3 0005-11-20  2 last2, first 1920   316003   0  0 50   0  0  0  0  0
#4 0005-11-20  3 last3, first 2021   316004   0  0  0 400  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: Thank you Prem for your time. It is close but it appended rather that replaced the "AY_##" column values with the value from the 1st column. So for example, if the cohort =1718 and the value in "ay_1718" = 700 then "ay_1819", "ay_1920" and "ay_2021" should also equal 700.

Comment: As you can probably figure it out I am a relative R newbie so I am still stumbling around somewhat. Anyway, I did figure out the reason the columns were appending is because of the case sensitivity of R. If I replace the statement  _mutate(cohort_plus3 = paste(paste("**AY**"_  with  _mutate(cohort_plus3 = paste(paste("**ay**"_ that will correct the append issue. Now, I need to figure out how to propagate the initial value to the ensuing three columns.

Comment: Thank you Prem! A brilliant elegant answer. Kudos to you and your effort is much appreciated. I clicked on the upvote but since I don't have the cred yet it doesn't appear. UT80

Comment: Glad that it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are two alternative approaches which reshape the data from wide to long format.

#### 1. `melt()` / `dcast()`

```
library(data.table)
long <- melt(setDT(inp)[, rn := .I], measure.vars = patterns("ay_"))
long[order(rn, variable), value := replace(value, which(value == 1L)[1L] + 1:3, 1L), by = rn]
dcast(long, rn + ... ~ variable)
```

> ```
>    rn    SYSDATE ID         name cohort fundCode ay_1718 ay_1819 ay_1920 ay_2021 ay_2122 ay_2223 ay_2324 ay_2425
> 1:  1 0005-11-20  0 last0, first   1718   316001       1       1       1       1       0       0       0       0
> 2:  2 0005-11-20  0 last0, first   1718   316001       0       1       1       1       1       0       0       0
> 3:  3 0005-11-20  0 last0, first   1718   316001       0       0       1       1       1       1       0       0
> 4:  4 0005-11-20  0 last0, first   1718   316001       0       0       0       1       1       1       1       0
> ```

#### 2. `gather()` / `spread()`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
inp %>% 
  group_by(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  gather(, , starts_with("ay_")) %>% 
  mutate(value = replace(value, which(value == 1L)[1L] + 1:3, 1L)) %>% 
  spread(key, value)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 4 x 14
> # Groups:   rn [4]
>   SYSDATE       ID name         cohort fundCode    rn ay_1718 ay_1819 ay_1920 ay_2021 ay_2122 ay_2223 ay_2324 ay_2425
>   <chr>      <int> <chr>         <int>    <int> <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
> 1 0005-11-20     0 last0, first   1718   316001     1       1       1       1       1       0       0       0       0
> 2 0005-11-20     0 last0, first   1718   316001     2       0       1       1       1       1       0       0       0
> 3 0005-11-20     0 last0, first   1718   316001     3       0       0       1       1       1       1       0       0
> 4 0005-11-20     0 last0, first   1718   316001     4       0       0       0       1       1       1       1       0
> ```

#### Data

```
inp <- fread('
SYSDATE     ID           name           cohort fundCode ay_1718 ay_1819 ay_1920  ay_2021  ay_2122  ay_2223  ay_2324  ay_2425
0005-11-20  000000000   "last0, first"       1718    316001    1         0     0         0        0         0        0       0
0005-11-20  000000000   "last0, first"       1718    316001    0         1     0         0        0         0        0       0
0005-11-20  000000000   "last0, first"       1718    316001    0         0     1         0        0         0        0       0
0005-11-20  000000000   "last0, first"       1718    316001    0         0     0         1        0         0        0       0')
```